# Haskell STM extension

Tags: haskell

I am looking for a Haskell STM extension that I read about in a paper some years ago. I still remember that on the one hand the authors claimed to have significantly improved Haskell STM, on the other hand they ran into inconsistencies in their measurements that they could not explain. I also remember that the authors were quite well know. Would anyone know what paper that was? I cannot find t back.

Comment: Random guess by [google scholaring](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=haskell+stm+improvements) around a bit: [the `unreadTVar` paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.90.7784&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: Thanks @luqui that is it! I did google scholar as well, but it did not show up for me. Google may use profiles when you are logged in.

Comment: @luqui Perhaps make it an answer so that the question can be closed the answer voted for?